Recaptcha error on Safari Web Inspector blocked from asking for credentials because it is a cross origin request
I get this error message below in console tab of Web Inspector of Safari.  Using recaptcha 2 (checkbox).
I don't see the same error on other browsers.
Blocked https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api... from asking for credentials because it is a cross origin request.

You ever figure this out?

I did not ; can you help?

No I have not but hoping to see something here that can help https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/561
